# Ruby 1.9.3: Recieving Stack Level Too Deep errors when creating a new object

Tags: ruby

I'm not exactly an expert in Ruby but I'm attempting to trace the issue in some scripts and haven't been able to reach the expert on this particular script to get an idea of why we're receiving this error. I've narrowed things down to this particular function and from what I can tell, the first print statement happens but the end print statement does not. The stack level too deep error only happens when this function exists exactly as below:

```
def load_power_ports(io_info)
  return if !io_info
  io_info.each_key do |key|
    print key
    if !@power_controllers[key.to_s.downcase]
      @power_controllers[key.to_s.downcase] = Object.const_get($equipment_table['power_controller'][key.to_s.downcase][0].driver_class_name).new($equipment_table['power_controller'][key.to_s.downcase][0])
    end
  end
  print "end of equipment power block"
rescue Exception => e
  raise e.to_s + "\nUnable to create power controller: " + io_info.to_s
end
```

The print statements are only to see which information is being passed, how far the program is getting and iterations being performed.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is break that big line of code out into smaller lines.  Then maybe you can find the line that's breaking.

Comment: Could you give the error stack also in your description,which would help for more investigation?

Comment: I actually was able to resolve it by finally realizing what the call to driver_class_name was really doing. Thanks! @Iiya-O helped by clearing my mind a little bit in the direction I was headed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the constructor of `driver_class_name` call `load_power_ports` directly or indirectly? If so, you'd end up having infinite recursion which would give you your stack overflow (oh the irony). That's the only place I can see where you'd likely have that issue.

Comment: Well you did expose a problem. It's actually that specific test equipment driver that has the issue. It is working swimmingly on the other power equipment definition. Thanks for helping me look in a slightly different direction. That specific call only pulls up the name on the input file from the user and directs the testing framework to use one type of power equipment or the other. No issues on the other version (which coincidentally works just fine). I just need to debug the faulty power equipment functions!